# AWS Linux Date vs node js Date

Tags: node.js, linux, amazon-web-services

I have an AWS Instance running node v10.15.1

From linux:-

```
$ date
Thu 14 May 16:12:40 BST 2020
```

BUT node shows...

```
$ node
> new Date()
2020-05-14T15:13:37.941Z
```

Now the actual time is 16:12, So Node is showing GMT, but the System knows it really is BST.

My `/etc/sysconfig/clock` contains:-

```
ZONE="Europe/London"
UTC=true
```

It's possible that a re-start might sort this, but I'm trying to find an alternative, less intrusive solution. - any advice appreciated.

Comment: System time should always be UTC. Convert to other time zones as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Date() in node always returns GMT time regardless of system time zone, you can convert to locale time :

```
[ec2-user ~]$ date
Thu May 14 17:38:13 BST 2020
[ec2-user ~]$ node
Welcome to Node.js v14.2.0.
Type ".help" for more information.
> d = new Date()
2020-05-14T16:38:54.746Z
> d.toLocaleTimeString()
'5:38:54 PM'
```